# ThreadAffinity being changed by OpenGL / ChoosePixelFormat

Tags: opengl, windows, win32, amd

If I change thread affinity and then create the window used in my OpenGL game it changes the thread affinity to something else. I tracked down the exact API call (`ChoosePixelFormat`) which changes it by calling `setThreadAffinityMask` after and before all the API calls. Strangely enough it is only the first call to `ChoosePixelFormat` which exhibits this behaviour. Is this when the OpenGL driver initializes itself and perhaps changes the thread affinity?

Has this been seen by anyone else and is there a reason why it is happening? For what it's worth I have a Radeon 290.